# Getting API info from C to Lua?

Tags: c, lua

how can I get a list of all C API functions with Lua?
For example, there are plenty C functions in a game(Crysis) which
can be called with

Lua:
g_gameRules.game:FunctionInC()

There are many functions I know but how can I get all available functions?

Comment: Isn't there some kind of documentation available?

Answer (score 1):

If `g_gameRules.game` is a table, traverse it looking for functions. If it is a userdata, look inside its metatable. (Also if it is a table.)

Answer (score 1):

There may or may not be an easy way to enumerate all of the C functions.

The `g_gameRules.game` may actually contain the functions, but this would be unusual. Something like the following will list these functions.

```
for k,v in pairs(g_gameRules.game) do if print(k,v) end
```

More likely `g_gameRules.game` will have a meta-table with an `__index` entry that is either a table or a a function. If the `__index` entry is a table the following will list all the functions.

```
for k,v in pairs(getmetatable(g_gameRules.game).__index) do print(k,v) end
```

This will only determine the names of the functions, the parameter list will still be an unknown.

If however, the `__index` value for the meta-table is a function, then there will be no easy way to list the functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,v in pairs(getmetatable(g_gameRules).__index) do 
    System.LogAlways(i.." : "..v); 
end
```

**OR**

```
    for i,v in pairs(g_gameRules) do 
    System.LogAlways(i.." : "..v); 
end
```